# subgraph information in supergraph

Tags: java, graph, subgraph

Hi i am using ParSemis : graph mining suite for subgraph detection. In that i use gSpan algorithm. The algorithm is written in java. i run the algorithm and able to get frequent subgraphs from database of graphs. I would like to know those subgraph instances in supergraph (i.e Graphs in database). i tried enabling storeEmbeddings in the option but i am not getting the details of subgraph embeddings. It simply return null values. Can someone help me.

P.S : The document says those embeddings can/will be stored in local object pool.

If so how to pull out those detail?

Comment: How large is your input graph? Any progress on this? Or did you move to using another tool?